# How do I use PHP in "Rewrite results" for a field in a view?

Tags: views

In a view, I configured a file to "Rewrite the output of this field." In the text area I need to use PHP. Can this be done?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot be done. You can write HTML code in the rewrite box. Please take a look at this if you need to write php code in Views: [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield)
Although I would suggest you create a template to add any custom php code you require.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to be more specific than Perisdr and to describe how to add template
for this field.
In view I went 'style settings', then checked 'use field template', added field.tpl.php to theme(in /modules/field/theme there is an example).

in this template you can rewrite everything.

Comment: but how to use replace token in template file?

Comment: i can't find this option "use field template"? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP field. Place it after the field you want to rewrite. Hide the initial field and use PHP to output the result.

This does quickly become opaque as noted it is best to go under 'advance', review the template choices (at the bottom of the column) and then put the php in the template.

I have also been trying to avoid this and use display suite and if an appropriate formatter does not exist write a custom formatter instead. There are examples for links such as 'image_link_formatter'.